# moz transition dont work but webkit yes

Tags: html, css, firefox, mozilla

First, sorry for my bad english. This is the problem: im creating a fan-made web (just for practice html5 and css3) and i try to put some animations. They work on safari, opera and chrome but no in mozilla firefox.

the css code is that:

```css
section figure img {
 padding:4px;
 margin: auto 5px;
 background:white;
 border-radius:20px;
 -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
 -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
 box-shadow:white 5px 5px 10px;
}
```

its one of the animation, i think if i can solved this i can solved the other animation dont-working.

Thanks for the support. :)

Answer (score 0):

You only use two prefixed transition properties and forget the rest.
Try this one:  ([and check the browser support of the property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp))

```
section figure img {
    padding:4px;
    margin: auto 5px;
    background:white;
    border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
    transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
    transition:transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
    transition:transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -webkit-box-shadow:white 5px 5px 10px;
            box-shadow:white 5px 5px 10px;
}
```